# Google App Script - Copy static chart to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dynamic chart in one spreadsheet, and I want to copy over a static version into another spreadsheet. Is there a way to do this with Google Apps Script?

I see the following method in the documentation, but there is no way to make it static from what I see.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var charts = sheet.getCharts();

for (var i in charts) {
  var chart = charts[i];
  // Do something with the chart
}
```

Comment: make it an image, or copy the source values and recreate the chart from the now-static source values.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly.